Expo React, use hook from outside a export default func app
I need assistance with expo and react Hooks
I need to manipulate the hook display (profil.tsx) from outside an app export. From the last file  login.js from a regular JS function.
Is there a way I can do this or do I need to restructure the code ??
Thanks a lot for your answers,
if you need further pieces of information to understand the problem don't hesitate to write what you need
thanks a lot!
Paul
        //profil.tsx
import { ProfileProvider, useProfile } from '../../components/profileContext';

    import abmelden from '../../components/login'
        
        
        export default function App() {
        
            const { display, setDisplay } = useProfile();//besonderer Hook...
        
        
          ...
        
        return (
        
        VIEW
        
        );}

Next file
//profileContext.js

import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ProfileContext = createContext();

export const useProfile = () => {
  return useContext(ProfileContext);
};

export const ProfileProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState('login');

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ display, setDisplay }}>
      {children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
};

Next File
//login.js


export default async function abmelden(showMSG = true){

    LOGOUT PROCESS... 
    
    Here I want to acces setDisplay to change the behavior of the Screen in profile.tsx
  
  }


React hooks cannot be accessed by non-react components or hooks. You can pass the setDisplay as an argument to abmelden and use it like that but it has to be within the context of a react component.
You can find some more information to these links :
legacy react documentation
stack overflow question 1
question 2
